# How to use an installed module - (Address autocomplete with Google Maps API)

Tags: php, google-maps, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

This is a pretty basic Drupal 8 question, but I'm new to this CMS and can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'm trying to use this module for address autocompletion using the Google Maps API: https://www.drupal.org/project/address_autocomplete_gmaps

The module is installed and enabled, but I can't seem to find reference to it anywhere outside the Extend tab.

My assumption is this module should enable a new field type, which I could embed in a custom block. But that doesn't seem to be the case - no new field type has appeared.

**Question:** I've installed this module, now how do I actually *use* it? The author shows it clearly working [here](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/laeva-2.png).

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a [Google Maps Javascript API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to be able to rely on Maps from your site.

Register the API key in the module configuration > `admin/config/system/address-autocomplete-gmaps`.

Now, since this modules relies on the [address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) module that provides the *Address* field type, in order to use it you might need to attach an *address* field to a content type of your choice, and then just enable the appropriate widget for that field (Address Autocomplete Google Maps widget). It will be exposed like any other fields when you edit an entity of the chosen type.

For users to be able to submit addresses independently from an entity edition, you need to build a simple form that reuses the field widget provided by the module. To do this have a look at the *formElement* method to see how it works :
(`Drupal\address_autocomplete_gmaps\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget::formElement`)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm confused about 2 things:  1) Adding an Address field to a content type makes it so an _admin_ must enter an address when adding content, right? How do I instead make the field visible on the actual website? 2) I don't see mention of widgets anywhere, can you point me in the right direction or show a simple example?

Comment: 1) No, I meant an admin need to add (if not already) an address field to the targeted content type, and for that field select the appropriate widget. Admin path is : `/admin/structure/types/manage/<your-content-type>`. You need to read [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/administering-drupal-8-site/managing-content-0/working-with-content-types-and-fields) for more information. 
2) cf. 1 ;)

Comment: I think I'm very close now. The widget works, but I still haven't been able to display the Address field on the site itself. If I add it as a field for a custom content type, it only exposes the Address field to Drupal users for creating/editing content... but how do I display the field on the actual website? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my answer to address (huhu!) your additional questions. If you need more information about how to deal with a plugin field widget as a form element, I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: @Hundley how do you ended up with it working on a standalone page? I am trying to do the same, its working on node edit/create page but not on any front end page i want to.